# De Broglie wavelength for electron and muon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, particle-physics, momentum, electrons

Given a 100 eV electron, I have to find its De Broglie wavelength. I do this by finding its momentum $p=\sqrt{2m_eE}$ and then using $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$.
I then wanted to repeat the same procedure by considering a 100 eV muon instead. I changed the value of the mass to $207 m_e$ and inserted it in the equation. However, the result I get is missing a factor of $\sqrt{10}$. I have been told I should have considered the impact of the mass on the energy as well when doing my calculations, but I do not understand why. Surely if the energy of the muon is 100 eV it keeps that value, if it is defined to be so in the problem data...

Comment: missing root ten compared with what?

Comment: Compared to the result I am given, which should be the correct one.